# No module named 'trading_calenders'

Tags: anaconda, conda, zipline

I am using zipline.  i actually dont see it in my site-packages for this environment.

```
    from trading_calendars import register_calendar, TradingCalendar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-373a8d5bd27d> in <module>()
----> 1 from trading_calendars import register_calendar, TradingCalendar

ImportError: No module named 'trading_calendars'
```

However When i look at the Anaconda navigator, it shows trading-calendars 1.11.1 and so i am not able to figure out where anaconda is showing it from. this makes no sense. how can i cleanup this config?

[image]

Comment: Can you run it from the command line successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I'm fairly sure there's a bug in this version of Navigator where changing the environment through the GUI doesn't actually change the active environment. You can check by running the following code:

```
import os

print('CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV:', os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'])
print('CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER:', os.environ['CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER'])
```

If you get the same output regardless of how you set the environment then you're seeing the same thing as me:

```
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: base
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (base)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that TradingCalendar came in as part of zipline and i messed around with it. so i just trashed my old environment and created a brand new one. its all kosher now